# AWS Aurora MySQL 5.7.12 accent sensitive collation

Tags: mysql, collation, amazon-aurora, utf8mb4

A legacy SQLServer db column has the collation SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS (Case Insensitive, Accent Sensitive).

We need to migrate this column into an already created and actively used AWS Aurora MySQL instance.

MySQL 8 has the collation utf8mb4_0900_as_ci (Case Insensitive, Accent Sensitive).

AWS Aurora however currently uses MySQL 5.7.12 which does NOT have utf8mb4_0900_as_ci. MySQL 5.7.12 does have

- utf8mb4_bin (Case Sensitive, Accent Sensitive as it is comparing binary)
- utf8mb4_unicode_ci (Case Insensitive, haven't been able figure out if it's Accent Sensitive)
- utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci (Case Insensitive, haven't been able figure out if it's Accent Sensitive)

Are utf8mb4_unicode_ci or utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci accent sensitive? If yes, can I just use one of them (but which?).

Otherwise, I see no other option but using utf8mb4_bin as it appears to be the only accent sensitive collation available, but because it is Case Sensitive I would have to work around the case sensitivity by eg lowercasing in WHERE clauses, but will that work without unintended undesirable side effects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

900 refers to Unicode 9.0 (best, but new with 8.0)
520 refers to Unicode 5.20 (best available in 5.7)
`_unicode_ci` refers to Unicode 4.0 (old)
`_general_ci` (even less sophisticated)

`_ci` (without `_as`) means case *and* accent *insensitive*.
`_bin` means case *and* accent *sensitive*; the bits are compared.
MySQL does not provide many collations that mix the sensitivities.

Use `SHOW COLLATION;` to see what collations are available in your system.